# Text-to-speech TTS in Spanish

Tags: text-to-speech, freertos, arduino-esp32

Good evening, I would like to know if someone could guide me in some way to work on a text-to-speech converter, that is, (TTS) in Spanish. I am very grateful for the attention provided and to the people who help me.

I was looking and I only found ways to use a tts in arduino in English and I would like it to be in Spanish and esp32.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How does this TTS work? You want to make speach from text saved in MCU, or you just need to import "data_array" where are already 8bit samples of some sound which is already prepared in PC? So basicly TTS run on PC and you just grab the data of sound to the MCU?

Comment: @WITC good afternoon, thanks for answering, in general my intention is to design an audio output from a data calculated in the code, that is, assuming that I use a temperature sensor that if I press a button it will tell me the temperature of that sensor in Spanish and English, but since it is my first time finding out about the subject, I would like to know how to do it and if someone from this forum would have the idea of how to do it to guide me.